# CompletableFuture does it cancel automatically when I do a get and an exception is thrown?

Tags: java, asynchronous, future, completable-future

I do something like the following in my code.

```
CompletableFuture<FOObar> f =  doSomething();
Foobar foo = f.get(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

if `get` throws any `Exception`, whether it is `TimeoutException` or otherwise, what happens to the future. Is it cancelled by default, or should I do

```
try {
f.get(timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
catch {
  f.cancel(true);
}
```

and hence future is released. 
if I don't cancel explicity, does the future hangs on to the thread, eventually leading to starvation if all threads are stuck in that state

I need to block on `get`, since I need the `foo` to perform further logic.

Comment: IIUC, it'snot "canceled", but `completeExceptionally() ` is called. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#completeExceptionally-java.lang.Throwable-

Comment: what happens to the future? is it blocked/released to pool? would it lead to starvation or special handling needs to be done to release it?

Comment: "Since (unlike FutureTask) this class has no direct control over the computation that causes it to be completed, cancellation is treated as just another form of exceptional completion. Method cancel has the same effect as completeExceptionally(new CancellationException())" from javadoc (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.HTML)

Comment: so thread starvation is unlikely to happen no matter whether if `get` succeeds succesfully or not? is that understanding right?

Comment: where do I see the `get` invokes `completeExceptionally()`.In the link it is mentioned otherwise, that calling `completeExceptionally()` will invoke `get` and not the otherway round

Comment: "I need to block on get, since I need the foo to perform further logic." - then why don't you use `doSomething().thenAccept(foo -> foo.performFurtherLogic())`?

Comment: @daniu well I am sending the return value up the stack where it is used for other transaction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the JavaDoc, when calling [`get(timeout, unit)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#get-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-), 4 exceptions are possible:

- `CancellationException` - if this future was cancelled
- `ExecutionException` - if this future completed exceptionally
- `InterruptedException` - if the current thread was interrupted while waiting
- `TimeoutException` - if the wait timed out

The `ExecutionException` is the most straightforward one: the future completed execeptionnally, which usually means that the task ended by throwing an exception (but it could also mean that something else completed the future with an exception).

The last 2 are related to the waiting of the `get()` call itself, and they only indicate that the future was not completed yet when the exception was thrown.

The `CancellationException` indicates that the future was `cancel()`ed, but does not indicate whether the job is still running or not.

The thing is that calling [`cancel(boolean)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#cancel-boolean-) does not, by default, cancel the running job, even when the argument is `true`:

> **Parameters**
>
> `mayInterruptIfRunning` - this value has no effect in this implementation because interrupts are not used to control processing.

So, by default, it does not matter whether you call `cancel()` or not because it will not affect the running job.

If you want to stop the running job, you have to implement a specific mechanism to support it in the method that creates the `CompletableFuture` (here `doSomething()`). It could for instance check if the returned future is cancelled, or provide some other callback mechanism to stop the execution (e.g. by setting a `stop` flag somewhere).

Comment: I get this. But my question is what happens to future if any of these exceptions are ? Do I need to do something like the try block code to release thread back to pool. I am seeing thread starvation issue. Is it possible to happen here

Comment: That's what I'm describing at the end of my answer: out of the box, there is nothing you can do. You have to change the implementation of `doSomething()` to be able to handle this, but the solution will be specific to what it is doing. I wonder if it wouldn't be better if you posted a separate question about your thread starvation problem.